# Mysql (LEFT)JOIN how to explain such behaviour?

Tags: mysql, sql

**With LEFT JOIN**

```
SET @foo:=0;
SELECT @foo 
FROM test t1 
  LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.id=t1.id AND (@foo:=@foo+1);
```

prints 0,0,0,0,0,0,0…

**but with JOIN**

```
SET @foo:=0;
SELECT @foo 
FROM test t1 
   JOIN test t2 ON t2.id=t1.id AND (@foo:=@foo+1);
```

prints 1,2,3,4,5,6…

Anybody knows? Thanks!

UPD. This queries produce the same rows except @foo value

Comment: Have you compared the two `EXPLAIN SELECT`s? I don't know it this helps, but http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/

Comment: That's an interesting question in itself. You can however do `SELECT @foo := @foo+1` to work around the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignments for session variables don't work inside `ON` clause.

The reason you see @foo incremented for INNER JOIN is that optimizer runs your query as:

```
SET @foo:=0;
SELECT @foo 
FROM test t1 
   JOIN test t2 
   WHERE t2.id=t1.id AND (@foo:=@foo+1);
```

Using `EXPLAIN SELECT...` you should see `using where` in extra column.

You can also use `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT...` and then `SHOW WARNINGS` to see how exactly optimizer runs your query.

In your case the `LEFT JOIN` query is run exactly as it is written, as for this type of join you can get different results for the same condition in `ON` and `WHERE`.

If you want to increment @foo for `LEFT JOIN` use:

```
SET @foo:=0;
SELECT @foo 
FROM test t1 
  LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.id=t1.id
  WHERE @foo:=@foo+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, mysql engine doesn't check second condition in AND sequence if first one returns false which is possible with LEFT JOIN

Comment: This can be only applied to OR lazy condition but not AND. Cause in AND both operators MUST be calculated to find out if result

Comment: Also I would assume that the test table is the same in both examples.

Comment: Ups. I'm noob ) You are right ) AND can skip right calculation if left operator is FALSE

Comment: If you SELECT @foo; after the first SELECT, what is the output in both the INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN cases? I would expect them to both be the same despite the output above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mention to select some additional data from your table t1?
The difference between both operations could be the behaviour of LEFT JOIN. LEFT JOIN tries to JOIN according the rules. Its picking a record from the dataset lefthand and tries to JOIN additional data from the dataset righthand. If there is no match all columns of the dataset righthand is set to NULL and joined. Normal JOIN skips records where no JOIN can be made.

```
id
--
1
2
3
4
```

LEFT JOIN picks record a, tries to LEFT JOIN other records. Every record whose ID is not like a's ID will result in a fail-JOIN. But LEFT JOIN does not skip those records because the required leftside-data (record a) is available. So the resulting record is filled with NULLs for the joined record and foo is not incremented.

Comment: Adding additional data makes same result. For example SELECT *, @foo makes same result.

Comment: Another interesting thing is that this two queries produce the same result except @foo value )